# Incompatibility between french babel and fnpct \multfootnote

Tags: footnotes, babel, french, fnpct

I would like to use babel with the `french` option and the multiple footnotes provided by the `fnpct` package (`\multfootnote`). But when I do, only one footnote is created instead of multiples.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\begin{document}

Some text\multfootnote{first;second;third}.
% creates only one footnote instead of three. 

\end{document}
```

The french `babel` documentation says that it saves the original definition of
`\@footnotemark` at the `\begin{document}` (p.64).

The `fnpct` documentation only indicates that french babel redefines `\@footnotemark` and that fnpct resets this redefinition (p.5).

Is it possible to have both french `babel` and multiple footnotes from `fnpct` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

babel makes the semicolon active a \begin{document} and so fnpct no longer recognize it as a delimiter. You can reset the delimiter after \begin{document} (or choose some other char as delimiter):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\begin{document}
\setfnpct{mult-fn-delim = {;}}
Some text{\multfootnote{first;second;third}.}


\end{document}
```

[image]